# Safe to remove empty keys from URLs?

Tags: http, url, url-parameters

My understanding in URLs are somewhat limited but I do understand the basic concept of domain name, sub-domain and parameters like `key=value`. However, at the moment I'm working with some ugly URLs provided from affiliate-companies. I manage those by setting up 301 redirects.

If I receive one of those ugly links they sometimes end with a key but no value like `www.example.com/affiliate?id=123&trackid=` ending with a key "trackid" but no value makes no sense to me.

Is it safe to remove that parameter in my example everything after the "3"? Making the URL `www.example.com/affiliate?id=123`.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is supplied to the server as-is, so the server can see the entire string and realize wether an parameter is set without a value or if it is left out.

However, server code usually does not differentiate between the two and handle empty parameters like undefined parameters. So it is possible for the server to technically see the difference, but they usually just handle both the same way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So to summarize; It's safe to remove "incomplete" parameters?

Comment: In most real-world cases, yes. It still depends on the server-software though, so there might be a few cases in which the server actually does differentiates.